# Fastest validation of sorting vector of pairs of elements until they are unorderly paired

Tags: r, algorithm, sorting

I have an unsorted vector of length N. Each element of the vector appears is present precisely twice (the vector length is an even number). I have a custom sorting algorithm, and the goal is to iterate until the vector achieves a state in which each element is adjacent to its copy.

`Unsorted vector = {A,F,J,E,F,A,J,E}`

`A valid sorted state = {A,A,J,J,E,E,F,F}`

`Another valid sorted state = {J,J,A,A,F,F,E,E}`

So my question lies in what is the fastest way to check if a sorted state is valid so that I can speed up my iterations? For long vectors, this will dictate most of my scaling ability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option involves converting the `vector` (as the `length` is `even` and an element is present exactly twice)  to a two-row matrix, get the `unique`and test whether the number of rows is 1.  If values duplicated are adjacent, while adding the `dim` attributes with `matrix`, the second row will be exactly the same as the first

```
f1 <- function(x)
{
nrow(unique(matrix(x, nrow = 2))) == 1
}
```

-testing

```
> v1 <- c("A", "F", "J", "E", "F", "A", "J", "E")
> v2 <- c("A", "A", "J", "J", "E", "E", "F", "F")
> v3 <- c("J", "J", "A", "A", "F", "F", "E", "E")
> f1(v1)
[1] FALSE
> f1(v2)
[1] TRUE
> f1(v3)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or slightly more faster

```
f2 <- function(x) 
  {
  sum(duplicated(matrix(x, nrow = 2))) == 1
}
```

-testing

```
> f2(v1)
[1] FALSE
> f2(v2)
[1] TRUE
> f2(v3)
[1] TRUE
```

-benchmarks

```
#thelatemail
> f3 <- function(x) all(duplicated(x) == c(FALSE,TRUE))
#TarJae
> f4 <- function(x) {rle_obj <- rle(x); all(rle_obj$lengths > 1)}

> x1 <- rep(1:1e8, each = 2)
> system.time(f1(x1))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.649   0.456   3.111 
> system.time(f2(x1))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.258   0.433   2.694 
> system.time(f3(x1))
   user  system elapsed 
  9.972   1.272  11.233 
> system.time(f4(x1))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.051   3.281  10.333
```

Answer (score 5):

Something quick and dirty but I'm not sure it will always work:

```
all(duplicated(x) == c(FALSE,TRUE))
```

This is relying on the fact that the two same values will always be next to each other, one not-duplicated, the next duplicated. Seems to work with the test sets:

```
x <- c("A", "F", "J", "E", "F", "A", "J", "E")
s1 <- c("A", "A", "J", "J", "E", "E", "F", "F")
s2 <- c("J", "J", "A", "A", "F", "F", "E", "E")

all(duplicated(x) == c(FALSE,TRUE))
#[1] FALSE

all(duplicated(s1) == c(FALSE,TRUE))
#[1] TRUE

all(duplicated(s2) == c(FALSE,TRUE))
#[1] TRUE
```

And is pretty quick, looking through a million length vector in 5 hundredths of a second on my machine:

```
x <- rep(1:1e6, each=2)
system.time(all(duplicated(x) == c(FALSE,TRUE)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.04    0.00    0.05
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `rle` function:

```
v1 <- c("A", "F", "J", "E", "F", "A", "J", "E")
v2 <- c("A", "A", "J", "J", "E", "E", "F", "F")
v3 <- c("J", "J", "A", "A", "F", "F", "E", "E")

rle_obj <- rle(v3)
all(rle_obj$lengths > 1)
```

test:

```
> rle_obj <- rle(v1)
> all(rle_obj$lengths > 1)
[1] FALSE

> rle_obj <- rle(v2)
> all(rle_obj$lengths > 1)
[1] TRUE

> rle_obj <- rle(v3)
> all(rle_obj$lengths > 1)
[1] TRUE
>
```